# Prov that if Null(A) is orthogonal to Col(A) then A is symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra

I wonder how to prove that given a square matrix $A$, if $Null(A)$ is orthogonal to $Col(A)$ then $A$ is symmetric. Proving the other direction is easy but this one gave me a hard time.

Comment: Does equal row space and column space imply the matrix is symmetric?

Comment: I see - so I can't prove it because it is not true :)  If it was true then every  invertible matrix had to be symmetric.